# Access Fragment Element from calling Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Is it even possible to access Views inside of a Fragment from the calling Activity. Or do i have to put all the needed Information into the `Bundle` when calling `NewInstance` or by using a static Method inside of my Fragment

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ActivityNavigationLayout);
    var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
}

private void SetUpFragmentManager()
{
    var frag = OverViewFragment.NewInstance();
    var fm = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    fm.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, frag);
    fm.Commit();
}
```

When `Resource.Id.Button` is part of Fragment inflated inside that Activity?

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to access the fragment views from activity? Could you please explain your requirement?

Comment: Use case is, Activity is started -> a Fragment replace is commited -> initialize some property on a view. Current Problem is if i do that the Fragment has not yet been inflated and therefore FindViewById returns null.

Comment: If you have to update any fragment property.. do it in the fragment itself in onCreateView method.

Comment: Why do you need to access the fragment views from activity? Why not access view in the fragment `rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button)`